# C++ Vector Not Initialized Empty When In Release Mode

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, c++14, release

This is one of the more vague errors I have posted on stack overflow so I'm sorry in advance if it seems a little lacking in information. I have a fairly large scale project that uses static vectors to contain information for the life cycle of the application. In debug mode everything goes off without a hitch, but in release mode the vectors seem uninitialized. When I step through the solution I can see that in release mode the vectors have a random size and are filled with nonsense that changes every time I run the application which leads me to believe that they are uninitialized and just reading random information from the heap. Do to the large scale of the project it would be difficult and unfair of me to display all of the code and ask for assistance in parsing through the whole thing so I have extracted the pertinent information. The problem in doing so is that the same error does not occur in the extracted code, as if the build undergoes different optimizations and as such will not produce the same error.

An overly long story short I was wondering if their was a way that I could force the initialization of the vectors with a size of 0 so that such an initialization will not get optimized out.

If it helps here is extracted code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::getchar;
using std::vector;
class Entity {
public:
    short id;
    Entity(short i) : id(i) {

    }
};

class EntityManager {
    static Entity& CreateEntity(vector<Entity> &entities, unsigned short i);
public:
    static vector<Entity> dynamicEntities;
    static vector<Entity> staticEntities;

    static Entity& CreateDynamicEntity();
    static Entity& CreateStaticEntity();
};

vector<Entity> EntityManager::dynamicEntities;
vector<Entity> EntityManager::staticEntities;

Entity& EntityManager::CreateEntity(std::vector<Entity> &entities, unsigned short i) {
    entities.push_back(Entity((entities.size())));
    Entity& entity = entities.back();
    return entity;
}

Entity& EntityManager::CreateDynamicEntity() {
    return CreateEntity(dynamicEntities, 1);
}

Entity& EntityManager::CreateStaticEntity() {
    return CreateEntity(staticEntities, 0);
}

int main() {
    Entity& e = EntityManager::CreateDynamicEntity();
    std::cout << e.id;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The order of initialization of global variables defined in different translation units is unspecified. My guess would be, you have a global object `A` whose constructor depends on the state of another global object `B` defined in a different source file. It just so happens that `A` gets initialized first, and when its constructor attempts to access `B`, the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik alright that makes sense to me, is there anything I can do about it? The EntityManager class is almost entirely static so I'm not sure if calling its constructor will help much

Comment: You could use a singleton pattern, where the singleton is created on demand, the first time it's used. Something like this: `class Singleton { static Singleton& GetInstance() { static Singleton instance; return instance; };` Make those vectors normal (non-static) data members. You could keep static member functions, which would simply forward to non-static member functions on `GetInstance()`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay so to make sure I understand this correctly, I would create a singleton for each static vector and access these vectors through their respective singleton wrappers?

Comment: You could. Personally, I'd turn the whole `EntityManager` into one singleton, and make vectors non-static members.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That seems like a good idea since I really only ever need one of them, I think I'll give it a shot, thanks for your help (especially with the whole unordered initialization of global variables thing, its kind of weird not knowing if the variables are gonna be initialized before you want to use them, but now at least I know what to look out for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems seems to be caused by the fact that order of initialization of global variables is not deterministic.

One way to make them deterministic is to wrap the data with functions.

Instead of using

```
vector<Entity> EntityManager::dynamicEntities;
```

use

```
vector<Entity>& EntityManager::getDynamicEntities()
{
   // This guarantees that entities is initialized properly 
   // before it is accessed by calling code.
   static vector<Entity> entities;
   return entities;
}
```

Of course, that would mean changing `EntityManager` to:

```
class EntityManager {
    static Entity& CreateEntity(vector<Entity> &entities, unsigned short i);
  public:
    static vector<Entity>& getDynamicEntities();
    static vector<Entity>& getStaticEntities();

    static Entity& CreateDynamicEntity();
    static Entity& CreateStaticEntity();
};
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, wouldn't `static vector<Entity> entities;` go out of scope once the `getDynamicEntites()` was finished? Also doesn't this initialize a brand new vector every time I try to access the dynamic entities?

Comment: @Ryoku, no, they won't. `static` variables are guaranteed to live across all calls to the function. They will be alive as long the program is alive.

Comment: Wow, that's cool had no idea. So that means it also shouldn't create any additional overhead "insuring" that its initialized properly first. That is it shouldn't have to execute the `static vector<Entity> entities` line more than once for the lifetime of the program (as opposed to executing and not doing anything every time I try to access one of the vectors), correct?

Comment: @Ryoku, that is indeed the case.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you so much! I'm still (obviously) new to the non determinism of global variable initialization (as in I didn't know it was a thing until minutes ago). I'm gonna have to look into that one. It seems a little scary not being able to guarantee the initialization of something before you need it. Also I thought this was going to be a lot harder of a problem seeing as I couldn't reasonably replicate the problem, I am just amazed at how many helpful and wise people here are on stackoverflow, thank you once again

Comment: @Ryoku, wise is a stretch. Experienced? Definitely.